# dynamic pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, pivot, unpivot

I have a query that uses both pivot and unpivot at the same time and I got it working fine. The code is part of a stored procedure that gets called from a Excel Macro when user passes in the parameters from the form.

I cant seem to think of a way of making my "IN" string dynamic. The IN part is something like

```
pivot
  (
  Sum(numbers) for

  WeekNum in ([12*02],[12*03],[12*04],[12*05],[12*06],[12*07],[12*08],[12*09],[12*10],[12*11],[12*12],[12*13])
  ) as q
```

I am trying to make the IN clause dynamic. So, if a user types in 12*04 as their starting range and 12*16 as their ending range, the above code should change dynamically. I could pass the entire query as a string and then update it, but I am not sure if that would work. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work as long as you construct the SQL statement in the stored procedure dynamically and execute it via `sp_executesql`

Comment: To this end, I have a T-SQL based question. Consider the above string where you can find the position of the first * using charindex function. How would you find the rest of them?